# vocie chat using java and socket, delay when connect on LAN

Tags: java, sockets, delay

i'm codding voice chat using socket with java, two client talk success, but delay 1-2s. i don't know why. cause net speed or my code

thread player

```
public class player extends Thread{
public DataInputStream din = null;
public SourceDataLine audio_out;
byte byte_buff[] = new byte[256];
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while(din.read(byte_buff)!= -1){
                audio_out.write(byte_buff, 0, byte_buff.length);
            }
            audio_out.drain();
            audio_out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                din.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

thread recorder

```
public class recorder extends Thread{
    public DataOutputStream dout = null;
    public TargetDataLine audio_in = null;
    byte byte_buff[] = new byte[256];
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while(true){
                int data = audio_in.read(byte_buff, 0, byte_buff.length);
                //audio_out.write(byte_buff, 0, byte_buff.length);
                System.out.println("sending");
                dout.write(byte_buff);
                dout.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(recorder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                dout.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(recorder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

thread transfer

```
public class transfer extends Thread{
    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    byte byte_buff[] = new byte[256];
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while(din.read(byte_buff)!= -1){
                dout.write(byte_buff, 0, byte_buff.length);
                System.out.println("tranferring");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("voice disconnect");
        } finally {
            try {
                din.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(transfer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

run no problem , but delay about 1-2s, two client connect on LAN.
please help me

Comment: For starters, TCP can have substantial jitter, and that's one of the major reasons it's never used for voice chat. You should use UDP instead.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said, and success thanks alot :))

Answer (score 0):

There also is java's real time protocol `RTP`, I believe was made to address this type of issue.